# Two errors I'm getting in this C program. Deals with structures, arrays, and bubble sorting

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, structure, bubble-sort

First two errors:

```
cs1713p3.c:129: error: incompatible types in assignment
cs1713p3.c:131: error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
```

Lines 129 and 131 are parts of a bubble sort function I wrote, which is meant to sort an array of a structure called "Stock". Here's the code for the Stock structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    char        szStockNumber[7];           // Stock Number for a stock item
    long        lStockQty;                  // quantity in stock
    double      dUnitPrice;                 // price per unit of stock
    char        szStockName[31];            // name of the stock item
} Stock;
```

Here's the code I wrote for the sort:

```
void sortInventory(Stock stockM[], int iStockCnt)
 {
     Stock *temp;
     int i;
     int j;
     int bChange = 1;
     for(i = 0; i < (iStockCnt - 1) && bChange == 1; i++)
     {
         bChange = 0;
         for(j = 0; j < (iStockCnt - i - 1); j++)
         {
             if(strcmp(stockM[i+1].szStockNumber, stockM[i].szStockNumber) < 0)
             {
                 temp = stockM[i]; //line 129
                 stockM[i] = stockM[i+1];
                 stockM[i+1] = (Stock)temp; //line 131
                 bChange = 1;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Yeah, I tried typecasting each assignment with a `(Stock)` right after the equals sign in each line, but that didn't work.

Thanks to anyone who helps out! I have no clue what's going wrong and I can't seem to find any relevant information on the internet, I think it's too specific of a case, haha.

Answer (score 1):

`stockM` is an array of type `Stock`. `temp`, on the other hand, is an array of type `Stock*`. So, you are basically trying to assign the value of a variable of type `Stock` to a variable of type `Stock*` which is not allowed.

Change the type of `temp` to `Stock`.

Comment: Oh, I see that now! Thank you. Wow, that was stupidly easy, I feel dumb, hahaha.